# Limiting MoreLikeThis of Lucene to a subset of my documents

Tags: java, search, lucene, morelikethis

I am using Lucene to index the content of my site and provide a search facility. I also use Lucene's MoreLikeThis to generate a "related pages" facility for the site. My site is multi lingual, so I need to limit the MoreLikeThis to a specific language at a time.

Anyone has an idea on how to do this?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, except that in my use-case there are *thousands* of subsets that should all have segregated relevancy calculations. :-/

Comment: On further code reading, I suspect this would require a change to indexing and maybe even the index format. It looks like terms are just stored once & globally, bearing a doc count. Another approach might be a custom IndexReader that does the docFreq calculation each time, but I don't know at what cost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with just splitting into multiple indexes and then perform the MLT query. Otherwise it is too heavy of a request. I hope the Lucene developers will ov

Answer (score 0):

[MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/mlt/MoreLikeThis.html) returns a Query object.
`MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(ir);

 Reader target = ... // orig source of doc you want to find similarities to

 Query query = mlt.like( target);`

You could create a 2nd query that checks for language. Then wrap both queries using You could create a BooleanQuery, like so:

`BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    booleanQuery.add(MoreLikeThisQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    booleanQuery.add(languageQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);`

Not very performance efficient but it will get the job done if you have a small corpus.

Comment: Well, if you are currently running MLT on all of your content, then adding the language query should not worsen performance that much (MLT is much heavier than a simple filter).  
A truly performing solution will filter for language *first*, then have MLT operate on the set of filtered documents only (need to look into how MLT works internally to see if that's possible).